# Regex to check existence of numbers and special characters only

Tags: regex

I'm trying to allow users to register a username, as long as it doesn't have any special characters (e.g. $£*%&) or numbers in it.

I have made the following which works, but it won't allow for non-English characters. That is, if I put in some text like `विकिपी` then it matches as not being an alphabetical character which is not what I want.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+$
```

I want to allow users to type in their username in whatever alphabet they want. So they could use the English alphabet or Hindi or Chinese etc. It should only check the string for the existence of numbers and non-alphabetic characters.

Is there some kind of regex range to match for special characters?

Clarification: I need to check the username (string) entered into a form for any numbers and non-alphabet characters in order to flag it as invalid. So the regex needs to look at the string and if it matches a number or special-character then the server will throw an error. By flagging them as errors, I'm telling the user to only use characters in the alphabet of their chosen language.

Comment: `[:alnum:]` should be fine.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I can't seem to make that work. I get an error saying `POSIX named classes are only supported within a character class`

Comment: Then try `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Coldfusion(Java) you can check input using unicode property as well:

```
\\P{IsAlphabetic}
```

`\\P{IsAlphabetic}` matches any unicode non-letter.

**Examples:**

```
boolean a = "विकिपीडिया".matches(".*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*"); // false
boolean b = "विकिपीडिया7".matches(".*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*"); // true
boolean c = "-विकिपीडिया".matches(".*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*"); // true
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work. If I enter in some non-English text like `विकिपीडिया` then it comes up as a match when it shouldn't. The second one I can't test because I'm getting an error saying incomplete token.

Comment: I'm using ColdFusion which is based on Java.

Comment: Try that in regex101 and type in a number like 7. It doesn't match?

Comment: Okay I think my question is confusing. I'll clarify: I need to check the username (string) entered into a form for any numbers and non-alphabet characters in order to flag it as invalid. So the regex needs to look at the string and if it matches a number or special-character then the server will throw an error. By flagging them as errors, I'm telling the user to only use characters in the alphabet of their chosen language.

Comment: The Regex must check the string for the existence of any numbers and non-alphabetic characters. That's all. If a match occurs, then the string is invalid in my application.

Comment: Here is what I currently use `[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+$` which works perfectly EXCEPT it won't allow non-English characters.

Comment: You just need `\\P{IsAlphabetic}` for this. Check my updated answer.

Comment: How could i test this in regex101? Is it possible? I typed in `.*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*` into the Regular Expression bit but I can't seem to match your tests

Comment: I'm getting this error from that site `Illegal repetition near index 5 .*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.* ^`

Comment: Check this link http://fiddle.re/3v4kc6? You must enter `.*?\P{IsAlphabetic}.*` in regex textbox.

Comment: Seems to work nicely, thank you anubhava. Voted as answer

Comment: Is there anyway to negate this regex? So I can find in string the characters which are NOT matching the pattern `^ .*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*`

Comment: Yes you can use: `.*?\\p{IsAlphabetic}.*` with **lowercase `p`**