# Why won't this Regex work in REFind()?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I want to search a string to make sure it doesn't contain any numbers or non-alphabetic characters. From my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453635/regex-to-check-existence-of-numbers-and-special-characters-only/31453658) a Regex solution was proposed which seems to work using online testing tools. But I can't get it to work in this format:

```
<cfif REFindNoCase(".*?\\P{IsAlphabetic}.*", FORM.Forename)>
<p>Error, your name contains illegal characters</p>
</cfif>
```

It just allows illegal strings through without picking up on the illegal characters. So `myname1977` seems to be let through without showing the error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `REFind(".*?\P{IsAlphabetic}.*", FORM.Forename)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Reg Exp engine ColdFusion uses doesn't have all the power of Java. Something like this should do it for you:

```
<cfscript>
input = "विकिपीडि";
writeDump(isValidUsername(input));// YES

input = "विकिपीडि7";
writeDump(isValidUsername(input));// NO

input = "hello";
writeDump(isValidUsername(input));// YES

input = "hel lo";
writeDump(isValidUsername(input));// NO

input = "hello7";
writeDump(isValidUsername(input));// NO


function isValidUsername(input) {
    var pattern = ".*?\P{IsAlphabetic}.*";
    var Matcher = createObject( "java", "java.util.regex.Pattern" )
        .compile( javaCast( "string", pattern ) )
        .matcher( javaCast( "string", input ) );

    return !Matcher.matches();
}
</cfscript>
```

*Update*

I posted this in the comments but may be useful so adding it to the answer incase it's of interest:

If you're doing simple matching then strings in Java have built in support for Reg Exp so you should be able to just do this: `mystring.matches(".*?\P{IsAlphabetic}.*");` The createObject version is more 'reliable' as CF may change something in the future which breaks it.

Comment: Is there an equivalent regex that would work with CF's own regex engine?

Comment: @volumeone - Verify they do the same thing. I have not used it, so I am not sure.

Comment: @Leigh sadly they don't, I tested it and it fails

Comment: @volumeone - Is the reason you want to use the CF function because you do not have access to createObject? If so, add that restriction to your question so it is more visible.

Comment: @Leigh I do have access to CreateObject. I was just trying to keep my code a bit simpler that's all. Makes little difference in the overall scheme of things

Comment: @volumeone - Gotcha, but sometimes it is necessary to use java. Given that CF uses an older regex library internally, this may be one of those cases.  If you search the SO archives, you will see there is *some* "unicode" functionality you can duplicate with the CF functions. However, they too have limitations. So again, it is quite possible there may be no native CF equivalent here. (Granted it is all java under the hood anyway ;-)

Comment: If you're doing simple matching then strings in Java have built in support for Reg Exp so you should be able to just do this: `mystring.matches(".*?\P{IsAlphabetic}.*");` The `createObject` version is more 'reliable' as CF may change something in the future which breaks it.

Comment: Thanks, the matches() method works perfectly for my needs. Just out of interest - does creating a Java object use up more resources than using only CF's built in methods?

Comment: Not an expert on that, but I'd expect it to create one new instance which will be garbage collected, so I'd be surprised if you notice any impact on performance.

Comment: @volume one - CreateObject generates a proxy for java objects.  So in theory they might require a bit more resources. You would have to profile it to see if it is even measurable. My guess is no.  Java methods tend to be a wee bit slower, due to the use of reflection, but again it is usually not a noticeable difference in *most* cases.